# Как повесить переход по ссылке на произвольное событие. ReactJs. React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router

Я использую [вот этот компонент](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) все очень здорово и красиво, но я хочу вместо отображения вложенных блоков реализовать роутинг, используя react-router при клике на таб. Если я просто оборачиваю таб в тег Link, то пропадают стили, а я этого не хочу. Как добиться красивого роутинга, используя табы?

Вот в этом коде стили ссылки перезаписывают стили таба, а я этого не хочу.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
import {Link, IndexLink} from 'react-router';
import CommonStyles from './CommonStyles';

class TabMenu extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            slideIndex: 0,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Tabs
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.slideIndex}
                >
                    <Link to="/">
                        <Tab label="Main" style={styles.slide} value={0} />
                    </Link>
                    <Tab label="Tests" style={styles.slide} value={1} />
                    <Tab label="Videos" style={styles.slide} value={2} />
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TabMenu;
```

Comment: Может быть роутер позволяет затригерить переход по роуту вручную? В этом случае можно будет просто повесить onClick на таб и вручную активировать роут, без необходимости использовать компонент Link.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov мне тоже сразу такая мысль в голову пришла, но я до этой секунды не смог найти ее подтверждение в документации и исходниках. Опыта пока не хватает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У react-router доступен объект router в контексте...

```
class TabMenu extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object,
  };

  handleClick(...) { // тут нужно смотреть, что приходит после onChange tabs...
    this.context.router.push({
      pathname: '/users/12',
      query: { tab: 'hello' },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Tabs onChange={this.handleChange}>...</Tabs>;
  }
}
```

Тут можно глянуть подробней, что можно делать с router...
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#contextrouter

Comment: У меня ваш код ломает сборку. Как написать то же самое, используя ecmascript 6?